# Machine roles for server topology SP2010

Tags: memory, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two machines, both 2.4 GHz quad core machines. One has 4GB RAM, the other 8GB RAM.

Which server should be Web Front End, which should be Database server?

Comment: Chance that the link between the two computers will be the bottle neck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single magic answer for this.

A webserver can run very well on tiny hardware if all it does is serve static pages to a few users.  If it needs to serve hundreds of simultanious connections and do some server side magic (e.g. accept uploadd images, convert them locally to a identicsal format and display those) then it needs bigger hardware.

The same is true for the DB server. Without more information than you provided you will not get a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's for a Dev machine that will also have a front end component for demo. Very few concurrent connections. More intensity on data access per single user. Sounds like DB server should get the beef.